# Resharper Active hotspot disabling intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Sometimes I get this red box which disables intellisense and I have to press Esc a few times to get it back.  Not a big deal but it gets annoying after a while.  Anyone know how to disable whatever this hotspot thing is?

http://postimg.org/image/x61y97y3t/

[image: Resharper problem]

Answer (score 3):

You are using a ReSharper 'if statement' template it seems. you typed if and pressed tab probably. You are supposed to enter a value in the red box and then press tab. (other template require more steps to complete)

Comment: yes that's exactly when it appears. So the question is how to disable this behaviour? I just want normal Visual studio functionality for this, I don't use or need templates.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper > Options > IntelliSense > Completion Behavior > Replace keywords with Live Templates

Turning this off made the usual completion available again in IntelliSense while leaving the Live Template as an option farther down.

The other option is to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> while in a Live Template to activate the "normal" IntelliSense.

Comment: still doesn't work for me. Tried disabling everything to do with intellisense in resharper and still disables intellisense. Driving me so crazy I'm about to uninstall the stupid thing.  It's like they tried to come up with a feature to degrade productivity rather than enhance it!  https://imgur.com/a/p57Q76y